# PATCH multiple resources

Tags: json, rest, http, api-design, http-patch

**Short:** Is it standard-compliant, RESTful and otherwise good idea to enable PATCH requests to update a collection of resources, not just a single one, but still individually?

**Long**:

I'm considering exposing a method for enabling batch, atomic updates to my collection of resources. Example:

```
PATCH /url/myresources
[
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/1",  // ID if the individual resource
        "value": 
        {
            ... full resource representation ...
        }
    },
    {
        "op": "remove",
        "path": "/2"
    },
    {
        "op": "replace",
        "path": "/3/name",
        "value": "New name"
    }
]
```

The context is a public API of a commercial solution. The benefits of allowing such PATCHes is the atomicity as well as batch-friendliness without spamming requests, handling failures individually etc.

I've consulted https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902 and https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789 but couldn't find a definitive answer if this is compliant. The RFCs mostly refer to "a resource", but a collection of resources could also be treated as such.

Is this a good idea? Are there better alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like this idea. A collection is a resource, too. So acting on it is perfectly good REST.

The semantic of your `PATCH` request would be that every subresource *not* listed in the request body is to be left as it is. Every subresource that *is* listed is to be changed as described. Yes, that sounds good to me.

As long as every segment of the request can be executed in a single request, I see no problems. Both your "all in one" request and single requests like this would be fine.

```
PATCH /url/myresources/1
{
    "op": "add",
    "value": 
    {
        ... full resource representation ...
    }
}
```